# Matlab determine index position in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

Hin everyone..I have matrix

```
col = [1 2 3 9 10 15 16 17]
```

I need to divide A into 3 with length B = [3 2 3],
result required :

```
col1 = [1 2 3] -> from col(1:3)
col2 = [9 10] -> from col(4:5)
col3 = [15 16 17] -> from col(6:8)
```

Thank you so much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that lenghts in B match col length, so every element is accounted for. If so, you can do it using simple for loop as follows:

```
col = [1 2 3 9 10 15 16 17];

B = [3 2 3];

start_idx = 1;
for b = B
    col_part = col(start_idx : start_idx+b-1)
    start_idx = start_idx+b;
end
```

Results in:

```
col_part =

     1     2     3


col_part =

     9    10


col_part =

    15    16    17
```

Answer (score 2):

`mat2cell` can be use:

```
A = [1 2 3 9 10 15 16 17];
B = [3 2 3];
mat2cell(A,1, B)
```

Result:

```
{
  [1,1] =

     1   2   3

  [1,2] =

      9   10

  [1,3] =

     15   16   17

}
```

Comment: Thank you @rahnema1

Comment: @rahnema1 nice. +1